Очистка картинки с капчей
Подскажите каким способом на пайтоне можно убрать эти линии с капчи.

Пробовал разные способы детекта линий, некоторые давали неплохой результат, но из-за разной толщины линии, приходилось использовать достаточно толстую закрашивающую белую полосу. От чего сильно ухудшалось качество самих иконок.
Была идея детектить места пересечения линий и не закрашивать эти области, но результат не получился.
Подскажите что прочесть именно по теме удаления линий, ну и как видим не обычного удаления, а оставляя точки пересечения с иконками. Всё что я нашел на данный момент выдает слабоватые результаты.

После нахождения прямой можно оценить её толщину и стирать с этой толщиной. Но лучше не стирать белой полосой а выполнять экстраполяцию с пикселов соседних со стираемой прямой. Вообще задача сильно упрощается тем что все стираемые прямые доходят почти до края картинки. Не очень стойкая капча.

А разве без удаления линий решить нельзя!?

@StanislavVolodarskiy Спасибо за ответ, а что дает то что прямые доходят до края? Посчитать точнее количество прямых? Иконка ведь тоже может зацепить край. Для меня это новая тема, может что-то посоветует почитать, по очистке таких прямых, или по детекту иконок? Мне кажется как вариант можно попробовать их распознавать через контуры. Попробовал пройтись по ним белыми линиями, а потом наиболее крупные куски иконки соединить вместе.  Но не думаю что это лучшее решение для последующего детекта.

@AnnaBazueva Спасибо за ответ, а вот не знаю. Мало опыта в этом. Но если хорошо очистить линии и удалить лишние точки, то такие иконки неплохо детектятся.
